# Cursor movement in comment edit-boxes broken

Tags: bug, android-app

Trying to move the editing cursor while editing a comment on android using the screen keyboard's arrow keys results in incorrect behavior.

Moving right or left causes the cursor to move in that direction, and *jump back to the first/highest line of the comment on the screen*. 
Moving up works as intended.
Moving down does nothing at all.

Using latest SE app on Android 4.2

Comment: What device? The behavior might be different for different devices. NVM, it's already reported.

Comment: Alcatel Pop C9. Latest firmware update. Using latest SwiftKey with no 'flow'.